# Cannot create broadcast receiver android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, p2p, android-broadcast

I have used the code provided by the android developer guides so that I can create a broadcast receiver but I have run into a problem.

Here is the code:

```
    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

It says cannot resolve symbol

> WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver

but if I try to change 
`BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;` to `WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;`

an error pops up, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver` is a custom class that you should define, and that is the reason why it is showing error.

You forgot to add a class named `WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver`.

Thus your `WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.java` will be like

```
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private WiFiDirectActivity activity;

    /**
     * @param manager WifiP2pManager system service
     * @param channel Wifi p2p channel
     * @param activity activity associated with the receiver
     */
    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,
            WiFiDirectActivity activity) {
        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
     * android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
                activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
            } else {
                activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
                activity.resetData();

            }
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an
            // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a
            // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.requestPeers(channel, (PeerListListener) activity.getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list));
            }
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P peers changed");
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            if (manager == null) {
                return;
            }

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                // we are connected with the other device, request connection
                // info to find group owner IP

                DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) activity
                        .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
                manager.requestConnectionInfo(channel, fragment);
            } else {
                // It's a disconnect
                activity.resetData();
            }
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) activity.getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
            fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(
                    WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));

        }
    }
}
```

The original file is available in [github](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.java) or in [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)